# Why targeting .Net Framework v4.6.1+ generates so many assemblies?

Tags: c#, .net, msdeploy

We have a library used so far in Framework 4.6 which generates 3 dll assemblies. As soon as we targeted 4.6.1 & 4.6.2, suddenly it creates a good deal of dlls. From looking at them, I would guess they all should be part of Framework. 
It's the same configuration and the same code, but targeting 4.6.1+ it creates a lot of Dlls.

```
<TargetFrameworks>net462;net461;net46</TargetFrameworks>
<AssemblyName>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</AssemblyName>  
<SignAssembly>true</SignAssembly>
<PublicSign Condition=" '$(OS)' != 'Windows_NT' ">true</PublicSign>
<PackageId>xxxxxxxxxxx</PackageId>

<PackageProjectUrl></PackageProjectUrl>
<PackageLicenseExpression>MIT</PackageLicenseExpression>
<RepositoryType></RepositoryType>
<RepositoryUrl></RepositoryUrl>
<RootNamespace>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</RootNamespace>
<GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
<DocumentationFile></DocumentationFile>
<PublishRepositoryUrl>true</PublishRepositoryUrl>
<EmbedUntrackedSources>true</EmbedUntrackedSources>
<IncludeSymbols>true</IncludeSymbols>
<ApplicationIcon />
<OutputType>Library</OutputType>
<StartupObject />
<GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
```

```
  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net46'">    
    <Reference Include="System.Web" />
  </ItemGroup

  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net462'">    
    <Reference Include="System.Web" />
  </ItemGroup
```

Our customers are not happy about it, wasting time figuring out which one is needed and which one is not.

Is there any option to exclude assemblies which come with the targeted framework?

Comment: What sort of dlls are being included that weren't before? Do you have examples?

Comment: Are you using visual studio? If so what version?

Comment: One way to do it without any third party tools is to remove all references then add what the compiler tells you to. Shouldn't take too long to reinstall them.

Comment: are you consuming any libraries that target netstandard? or that perhaps have a net46 and net461 TFM where the net461 build targets something netstandard transitively? basically: when net46* attempts to target anything netstandard (directly or indirectly) it has to fake it by referencing a *ton* of stuff into your project that is needed by netstandard but which isn't actually in net46*; this is largely fixed in net472

Comment: I am using VS2019Pro:

Samples of dlls:
System.AppContext.dll
System.Collection.dll
System.Collection.Generic.dll
System.Data.Common.dll
......

It's the same code, a library with 2 references which may or not have references in netstandard b/c 2 references are 3rd party tools. 

But exactly the same prj configuration and source code targeting 4.6 generates 3 dlls (1 + 2 dependences) -  while 4.6.1 and 4.6.2 generate 40-60 dlls.

Our customer is steaming and we have no good explanation.

Comment: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2019/Feb/19/Using-NET-Standard-with-Full-Framework-NET provides most of the backgrounds you need. Either you upgrade to target .NET Framework 4.7.2 and above, or you have to live with all those extra assemblies if you stick to any .NET Standard 2.0 dependencies. If you decide to get rid of those .NET Standard 2.0 dependencies, of course you can also get rid of them.

Comment: Marc Gravell - You are correct, 472 has fixed this issue!